# Have I installed 2 SSL letsencrypt certificate?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

Since yesterday, I was trying to install letsencrypt certificate on one of my subdomain text.example.com. Since example.com already had it, first I tried to "extend" it by adding another subdomain with "-d example.com -d test.example.com" option but then I saw that now LE supports wildcard too so I follow the instructions and I believe successfully installed it.

Now my concern is when I ran -

./certbot-auto certificates

it is showing me 2 entries

```
Found the following certs:
  Certificate Name: example.com
    Domains: example.com test.example.com www.example.com
    Expiry Date: 2018-07-09 08:10:54+00:00 (VALID: 88 days)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
  Certificate Name: example.com-0001
    Domains: example.com *.example.com
    Expiry Date: 2018-07-10 09:41:02+00:00 (VALID: 89 days)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/privkey.pem
```

Does this mean I now have 2 SSL Certificate for same domain? If yes, how to remove/disable one? which one will be taken as default? Is it safe to leave them as it is as things look like working fine?

Comment: Yep, you've got two certificates. There's not really any harm to having more than one. There's a `certbot delete` command if you really want to get rid of one of them - just make sure you update your Apache/nginx config that references that certificate.

Comment: Thanks,I guess I will leave them as it is then. If needed, will delete the 1st one and will keep the wildcard one.